# How to dynamically produce pictureboxes, via button click?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I'm trying to add pictureboxes dynamically to a C# win32 form for a near-production-quality application I'm trying to build, and I've got it pretty much down.

The problem I'm running into is that I can't seem to add pictureboxes or controls to the form dynamically, in a method. I have added them to the form via the Form1 initializing method, but if I add controls in, say, a button_click method, it simply doesn't add them unless I have a panel container, and type panel1.Controls.Add(stuff). But, then the picturebox appears in a completely different location than intended - and blocked by, apparently, the panel itself. Most of the picturebox is blocked by the panel, and part of it is -outside- the panel. I have no idea what's going on.

Here's the code I'm using that I learned online to add the pictureboxes, in a button click method:

```
PictureBox pb = new PictureBox();
        pb.Size = new Size(this.Size.Width / 14, this.Size.Width / 12);  //I use this picturebox simply to debug and see if I can create a single picturebox, and that way I can tell if something goes wrong with my array of pictureboxes. Thus far however, neither are working.
        pb.BackgroundImage = Properties.Resources.cardback;
        pb.BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Stretch;
        pb.Location = new Point(50, 50);
        pb.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Left;
        pb.Visible = true;
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Controls.Add(pb);
        PictureBox[] pbName = new PictureBox[totaldeckcount];
        for (int i = 0; i < totaldeckcount; i++)
        {
            pbName[i] = new PictureBox();
            pbName[i].Size = new Size(this.Size.Width / 14, this.Size.Width / 12);
            pbName[i].BackgroundImage = Properties.Resources.cardback;
            pbName[i].BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Stretch;
            pbName[i].Image = Properties.Resources.cardback;
            pbName[i].Anchor = AnchorStyles.Left;
            pbName[i].Visible = true;
            int x = 0;
            int y = 15;
            if (i > 10)
            {
                y += (int)((this.Size.Height * i) + 30);
            }
            x = (int)((this.Size.Width / 12) * Math.IEEERemainder(i, 10));
            pbName[i].Location = new Point(x, y);
            this.Controls.Add(pbName[i]);
        }
```

Cardback is a working texture, I've seen the thing pop up when I try making a picturebox with it in Form1's method, so that's not the problem. The problem doesn't -appear- to be my syntax, since I was able to copy the

```
PictureBox pb = new PictureBox();
```

code directly into the Form1 method and it executed just fine.

I can't find anything online via google, and this has me completely stumped.

Comment: Remove the second `InitializeComponent();` call which is inside the `for` loop.

Comment: And remove `pbName[i].Parent = this;`

Comment: @keyboardP No dice, same result. The only reason it's in there a couple times is because I was trying to make it initialize the pictureboxes, haha; but removing the one in the loop did nothing, same result. Nothing appears on the button click.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel That didn't help either.

Comment: You're not setting `Location` property anywhere

Comment: @SriramSakthivel Thanks - although you're right, that still didn't help either.

Comment: Now what happens, update the question with your current code

Comment: I did, I updated it, but the thing is, the result of running the code hasn't changed -at all-.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out, the problem is that there was a picturebox acting as a background image for the program, that was almost as large as the winform itself. The picturebox blocked all controls that were programatically created, thus giving the illusion of the code doing nothing.

Answer (score 6):

May this code help you to get concept :
This is the one i'm working for creating picturebox,textbox and button dynamically in flowlayoutpanel.

```
   PictureBox[] pics = new PictureBox[50];
    TextBox[] txts = new TextBox[50];
    Button[] butns = new Button[50];
    FlowLayoutPanel[] flws = new FlowLayoutPanel[50]
    static int brh =0; 


    for (int i = 0; i < totalnumbers; i++)
        {
            flws[i] = new FlowLayoutPanel();
            flws[i].Name = "flw" + i;
            flws[i].Location = new Point(3,brh);
            flws[i].Size = new Size(317,122);
            flws[i].BackColor = Color.DarkCyan;
            flws[i].BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Fixed3D;
            flws[i].Disposed += Form1_Disposed;               
            flws[i].Click += new EventHandler(butns_Click);

            pics[i] = new PictureBox();
            pics[i].Location = new Point(953, 95 + brh);
            pics[i].Name = "pic" + i;
            pics[i].Size = new Size(300, 75);
            pics[i].ImageLocation = "E:/image"+i;
            flws[i].Controls.Add(pics[i]);

            txts[i] = new TextBox();
            txts[i].Name = "txt" + i;
            txts[i].Location = new Point(953, 186 + brh);
            txts[i].TextChanged += Form1_TextChanged;
            flws[i].Controls.Add(txts[i]);

            butns[i] = new Button();
            butns[i].Click += new EventHandler(butns_Click);
            butns[i].Text = "submit";
            butns[i].Name = "but" + i;
            butns[i].Location = new Point(1100, 186 + brh);

            flws[i].Controls.Add(butns[i]);
            this.Controls.Add(flws[i]);
            flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(flws[i]);
            brh += 130;
        }  


 private void butns_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // you can add the procces to perform after dynamically created button pressed
     }
```

Comment: Sorry, but that didn't help me at all; I tried using a flowlayout panel made dynamically in a method in my code, but still, nothing appears on my screen. It's like I'm cursed.